# SQL Nested Subquery With In Keyword

Tags: sql

```
select distinct course_id
from section
where semester = ’Fall’ and year= 2009 and
    course_id in (select course_id
                  from section
                  where semester = ’Spring’ and year= 2010);
```

In the above SQL code, does the nested subquery run first by selecting the tuples in the section relation that have `semester = Spring` and `year = 2010`? Then when running the main select statement: `select distinct course_id` it will first select the tuples which have `semester = Fall` and `year = 2009`, but will also check if the `course_id` is present in the relation that was created in nested subquery before?

Comment: It depends on your RDBMS, indexing, size of your data, how grumpy the database is, and the past 12 month average cumulative rainfall in your city. Most RDBMS's have `EXPLAIN` built in. Stick the word `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and it should tell you about it's execution path.

Comment: If you are talking about MS SQL, run the query with the option "Include actual execution plan" (on the sql editor toolbar), and you will see what exactly happens in what order

Comment: Ok lol. I see the point now. Will try that. Thanks!